# Regex: how to find new line in code

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, adobe-brackets

I have a lot of html files with text without `<p>.` tags in the code.
I try  find and replace with Adobe Brackets or Sublime Text 2:

```
Find <br><br>\n
Replace </p>\n</p>
```

But they do not find the \n in the code

Simplified, now I have:

```
Some sentence, some sentence<br><br>
(I have one space here in the code)
Some sentence, some sentence<br><br>
```

I would like to convert:

```
Some sentence, some sentence</p>

<p>Some sentence, some sentence</p>
```

(I know I will have to add manually just one `<p>` at the beginning, this is not important and it is not the point of this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Find:(.*)<br><br>\n?
Replace:<p>\1</p>\n
```

**InPut**:

```
Some sentence, some sentence<br><br>

Some sentence, some sentence<br><br>
```

**OutPut**:

```
<p>Some sentence, some sentence</p>

<p>Some sentence, some sentence</p>
```

Comment: You should turn on regex mode, click `.*` button, it a list menu like`.* Aa “ ” ` and it on left-bottom.

Comment: Your regex makes sense, but I tried with Adobe Brackets find and replace with the icon .* (regex activated) and it literally writes me <p>\1</p>\n

Comment: It works very well with Sublime. I was too much time trying with Adobe Brackets. It seems that Brackets does not recognize \n

Answer (score 1):

Match a `br` with followed spaces (regex spaces includes `\n\r\t ...`):

```
<br\s*\/?>\s*
```

You can then replace with your string with global search.

Edit: I saw that your replacement is not just a carriage return, which will be messy with my example.
I would go for a two steps, replace any `br` by `\n` then apply your `p` elements by replacing multiple `\n\s*`.

Comment: The question here is that code editors do not recognize carriage returns or \n. If i make a replace <br> by \n they literally write \n

Comment: This works in Sublime: [link](http://pasteboard.co/NUvqfEK.png). Make sure regex mode is enabled (red arrow).